# What is the Azure Kusto command to show more columns in the table

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

By default In Azure AppInsight Logs, only some of columns shown in the table, click the arrow in left will show more content, but what is the command to add additional columns in the table?
I don't like "project", for which you need to specify all columns you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean that you wanna show all the columns like this? As you said, after executing the query, click the arrow in the left will show more content, that means the query has got all columns. So we only need to choose to `select all` to make all of them to show in the table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case you ended up here just trying to find an easy way to check all columns of a table:

```
.show table TableName

.show table TableName details

.show table TableName cslschema
```